# How to get user's pics who likes our post using restfb?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, servlets, restfb, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I am  trying to get the pic of a user who likes my post, i successfully get the names and id of a user who likes my post but i am not able to get this.
Is there any other method to get the pic of a user who like my post.
while using graph tool explorer i saw that the "pic" is the key to get a pics of user but when i try get by Likes.get(1).getpic(); it says getpic is undefined it means it doesn't have this kind of field, so is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/ID/picture'/>
```

where ID is a id of user for whom you want to get picture and then simply request to above URL you will get image.